# WSDL SOAP request in R

Tags: r

I'm trying to access an internal API that uses SOAP to make a call and then returns an XML response:

```
library(SSOAP)
library(XML)
library(XML2R)
library(RCurl)

wsdl <- processWSDL("http://10.139.21.109/ARTGEOLOCATORWS/artgeolocator.asmx?WSDL")
wsdl.iface <- genSOAPClientInterface(wsdl@operations[[1]], def=wsdl)
```

I get the error when I run the genSOAPClientInterface command:

```
 Error in (function (object, Class, strict = TRUE, ext = possibleExtends(thisClass,  : 
 no method or default for coercing “character” to “AddressScrubInfo”
```

Not sure how to get it working, any help out there?  I know I'm not making it easy since it is an internal facing API.